# Volatility of query results in asp

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, ado

I have seen a couple of instances now where some legacy code I'm working on exhibits what seems buggy behavior and I wonder if I just don't understand something.

```
  rsCaspio.Open sql, dbCaspio, ,adLockReadOnly
  response.write(rsCaspio("fieldname") & "<BR>")
  response.write(rsCaspio("fieldname") & "<BR>")
```

It will write the contents the first time but the second time it is blank.  Is this not unexpected and I just don't know something about queries or is there something really odd happening that I need to dig into deeper?  Perhaps results aren't guaranteed after the first read?  This code has been working but with a few changes it has suddenly gone blank.  The original programmer would read once and reference the result several times and in several routines which is scary, but the example above is from my debugging and the lines are right next to each other.

If it was asp.net I'd look for overloaded stuff or freaky pointer math since it's legacy, but that shouldn't be the case in good old ASP, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a BLOB/TEXT field by any chance?

Comment: In this particular case it's a string of 177 characters verified to be straight up ASCII letters, numbers, a colon, period, comma and spaces.

Comment: But is it stored in a BLOB/TEXT field or a varchar/char field? The reason that I ask is that I remember a long time ago a problem with reading BLOB fields with certain drivers.

Comment: I see.  It is indeed a TEXT field at one point.  Everywhere else a VARCHAR, but if it's a problem with BLOB/TEXTs then that could be it!

Comment: @Chris:  You should write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, pretty much as Chris just said. I found this problem occuring with older versions of SQL Server. I think the solution is any TEXT columns have to appear last in your select statement, and you can't read them twice.

I think there is nothing else you can do about it. Maybe update some ADO internals or SQL Server itself - possibly it is an obscure setting in SQL Server, but I never found it.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish Chris had done it as an answer but I am just reading into a variable once and accessing that multiple times for a solution.